# Programatically how to get all the details including TIME of all the reminder set in android phone..?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

In my application, Pro-grammatically I have set some reminders and now I wants to display all these details in a list format, I am getting some details (i.e. Date and Description), but I also wants to display the **`REMINDER TIME`**, but I don't know how to get the Reminder-TIME.

The code through which I'm getting some details (i.e. Date and Description) is as follows:

```
final ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), new String[]{"_id","title","dtstart","dtend","description","eventLocation"}, null,null, "DTSTART ASC");\
```

Thanks in Advance.!